# Why is `get_all_simple_paths` not visible in `python-igraph`?

Tags: igraph

I can see the method [`_get_all_simple_paths` defined in `GraphBase`](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/src/graphobject.c#L4672), and `get_all_simple_paths` defined in the [igraph `Graph` object (in GitHub)](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/igraph/__init__.py#L610), but when I actually instantiate one of those objects using a PyPi install of 0.7.1, the methods are not visible.

Why are they not visible and how can I make use of them (or a recommended equivalent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0.7.1 release of python-graph is [pinned to an older release of the igraph library](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/157).

Comment: The latest python-igraph, 0.8.2, exposes this method on the native library.